# Python RegEx matching each bracket element

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to come up with a regex for the following string:

```
[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"],[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"],[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]
```

I am trying to get as match output each bracket with its content as a single element like the following:

```
[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"]
[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"]
[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]
```

My initial naive approach was something like this:

```
(\[[^d],.+\])+
```

However, the .+ rule is too general and ends up matching the whole line.
Any hints?

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Is this a JSON string? Note that adding `[` and `]` from the beginning and the end of the string would make this particular string JSON loadable with `json.loads()`..

Comment: You can use `r'\[[^]]*]'`

Comment: I think you can also use `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: @dot.Py the `null` would probably need to be special-handled then..

Comment: @alecxe thanks for your info! so according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), the `ast.literal_eval()` works with `None` but don't works with `Null`..

Comment: Replacing the `null` with `None` and using `literal_eval` gives `([1, None, '7. Mai 2017'], [2, 'test', '8. Mai 2018'], [3, 'test', '9. Mai 2019'])`

Comment: It's good to be reminded of this ever once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the data format you are trying to parse and where it is coming from, but it looks JSON-like. For this particular string, adding *square brackets* from the beginning and the end of the string makes it *JSON loadable*:

```
In [1]: data = '[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"],[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"],[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]'

In [2]: import json

In [3]: json.loads("[" + data + "]")
Out[3]: 
[[1, None, u'7. Mai 2017'],
 [2, u'test', u'8. Mai 2018'],
 [3, u'test', u'9. Mai 2019']]
```

Note how `null` becomes Python's `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will output what you've requested using `\[[^]]*]`.

```
import re
regex = r'\[[^]]*]'
line = '[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"],[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"],[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]'
row = re.findall(regex, line)
print(row)
```

Output:

> ['[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"]', '[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"]', '[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]']

Consider changing `null` to `None` as it matches python representation.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the wonderful module [pyparsing](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/) to do this:

```
import pyparsing 

for match in pyparsing.originalTextFor(pyparsing.nestedExpr('[',']')).searchString(exp):
    print match[0]
[1,null,"7. Mai 2017"]
[2,"test","8. Mai 2018"]
[3,"test","9. Mai 2019"]
```

(Unless it is actually JSON -- use the JSON module if so...)